# Teaching vim to fold RStudio-like sections using foldexpr

Tags: regex, vim, syntax, comments, folding

I would like to make the `vim` to honour `rstudio`*-like* sections and enable folding for those blocks of text through `foldexpr`.

## Sections

The sections are fairly straightforward and correspond to blocks of text with a set of words and **`---`** signs until 80 characters, as illustrated below:

[image: RStudio sections as available on www.rstudio.com]

*Mor information on how the sections work is available [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections).*

## Problem

*How can I built `foldexpr` in vim so it recognises a section of format:*

```
# Word word ... ------------------------
```

### regex

The regex matching section could be of format:

```
\#[[:blank:]]([[:word:]]|[[:blank:]]){1,}\-{1,}
```

[***regex101***](https://regex101.com/r/GhGw1S/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=RFoldexpr(v:lnum)

function! RFoldexpr(lnum)
  if getline(a:lnum) =~ '^#\s\(\w\+\s\+\)\+-\+$'
    " Start a new level-one fold
    return '>1'
  else
    " Use the same foldlevel as the previous line
    return '='
  endif
endfunction
```

Putting this in the file `~/.vim/ftplugin/r.vim` should automatically evaluate it upon loading an R file. If you'd like to learn more about why it works and what other "features" you could add to it, try reading `:help fold-expr`.

Comment: For me the regex wasn't matching correctly because things like apostrophes caused it to miss the fold. I changed the regex to `'^#\s\(.*\)\+-\+$'` which seems to have fixed the issue in my test file.